# Replace Placeholder HTML comment with HTML element

Tags: html, ios, regex, nsregularexpression

I'm developing an iOS app that needs to display HTML content inside a HTML powered textview (DTCoreText).
For whatever reaso nthe client has decided to provide videos inside special HTML comments that I'm supposed to turn into a  tag.

The comment format is as such

`<!-- placeholder_video:url_of_video.mp4 -->`

I was hoping I could write a regex to match the entire comment, extract the content and replace it with a  element pointing to the correct URL through NSRegularExpression's stringByReplacingMatchesInString:options:range:withTemplate: but I can't for the life of me figure out Regular Expressions.

The best I could come up with is

```
(?<=<!-- placeholder_video:)(.*)(?=-->)
```

Which matches the comment's content (the mp4 URL), but I need it to match the entire comment instead and extract the content as a sub pattern (that I would later access through \1 if I understand correctly) so I can use a replace pattern to quickly replace the comment with the proper `<video src="url_of_video.mp4">` string

Can it be done? Or am I better off trying to do it in two passes instead? (match the entire comment then run another regex on that comment to extract the URL and replace the former?

Comment: "The comment format is as such" ... ? Think you forgot a rather important part to your question ;)

Comment: Oops, you're right! Fixed

Comment: Ok looks like I guessed it right in my answer then. The answer I posted bellow should work for you. There is a full working example at the end using javascript on a page, with a jsfiddle example as well (http://jsfiddle.net/72WeZ/). The example just gives you an alert with the result, if you want to replace the html just change it to $("#example").html(str2);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the way your question looks right now (Having forgotten to paste the example of how the comment looks) it's hard to give a good answer.

But since you mention that this:

```
(?<=<!-- placeholder_video:)(.*)(?=-->)
```

will manage to fetch the content of the comment. And since you say all you want is to capture the entire comment.

Then if I understand this correctly I would say all you really need to do is add a capturing group around your entire expression and drop the lookback and lookahead.

(Maybe also avoid grabbing the leading and trailing spaces)

```
(<!-- placeholder_video:\s*(.*)\s*-->)
```

When testing with the following:

```
<!-- placeholder_video: url_of_video.mp4 -->
```

I will get 2 groups:

```
1: <!-- placeholder_video: url_of_video.mp4 -->
2: url_of_video.mp4
```

You can also give your groups names if you like, to make it easier to reference them:

```
(?<comment><!-- placeholder_video:\s*(?<url>.*)\s*-->)
```

It is also true that you can use \n to reference group n **inside** the regular expression.

If you plan to replace the first capturing group with the second one in a single regex, then how you do it would depend on the language. Some languages like C# will allow you to provide your own replacing method, which is one option. But I'm assuming you're not in C# here.

In Javascript you can simply use $n to reference the n'th matched group as the replaced value. (You can also provide a function, but you don't need to)

A full working example in JS (Using jQuery but not needed):

```
<div id="example">
    <!-- placeholder_video: url_of_video.mp4 -->
</div>

<script>
    var str = $("#example").html();
    var str2 = str.replace(/(<!-- placeholder_video:\s*(.*)\s*-->)/g, "<video src=\"$2\">");
    alert(str2);
</script>
```

You can see the working jsfiddle example here: http://jsfiddle.net/72WeZ/

Comment: How would I go about and ignore any trailing spaces in the filename? I could hardcode them in the expression but I'm not entirely sure they will always have a space at the end of the URL before the closing -->

Comment: This should already be in the regex posted. \s* basically sais 0 or more spaces. Since the url won't have spaces within it, you could change (.*) to ([^\s]*) if you want to be absolutely sure. But I think it should work as it is already.